# "Create Task" quick action hidden on Lightning page

Tags: lightning, action

Anyone have experience with quick actions that won’t show up on a Lightning page? I’ve got one that creates a task. The user’s profile has access to the action’s record type and edit access to the tasks "Related To" field. Still no luck getting it to show up on the parent's page, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick action of type Task or Event appear under the Activity tab of the Lightning record page or under the Open Activities/Activities history related list.

Note that "Activities" component shows up only if the Activities View is set to Activity Timeline for the org or user.

More info about the activities view [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_records_record_activities_view.htm)